# Polymer and shadow DOM external styling

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

Hi I'm experimenting with Polymer and trying to style some polymer paper modules... In Polymer 1.0 they added this new properties in the CSS internal to shadow DOM's module... I am trying to change a color that is dependent on one of this properties `--paper-input-container-focus-color` for the [`paper-input-container`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) module but I could not find any clear documentation or guide on how to actually access that property from...

I can style it overriding the CSS property via `/deep/` or `::shadow` but from my understanding this new method is supposed to avoid using those 2...

Can anyone point me in the right direction???

**CLARIFICATION:**

I am interested in the [mixins](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) Google introduced in polymer... that make use of `@apply(--foo-bar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual I answer my own question... But I really hope it can help others not wasting days like I do..

to take advantage of this new mixins to customize your shadow-element externally you need to add a `style` tag with the attribute `is="custom-style"` in your page before placing the custom-tag.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    my-custom-module{
        --my-custom-property-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<my-custom-module></my-custom-module>
```

Comment: What's even more interesting is how you use <style is="custom-style"> as an external document and **split** the content of the document into several document, like we used to do in SASS.

Comment: That's because the whole point of Polymer is that it's made for modularity... Mixing and matching pieces from different documents without touching the source code of each module is great!

Comment: Tony, I get that. The thing is my external html doc is hundreds of lines already. Is SASS we use imports. Here we have one big external html file with <style is="custom-style"> in it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SASS however Polymer just graduated to stable version after a whole year of "beta" so to speak... Plus from what I understand this is a feature that is still under development. As for having one giant style sheet I'm not sure I get it... You can split your CSS across 1000 files as long as when you declare your `<style>` tag it has the attribute/value `is="custom-style"`so that polymer will use it for the shadow DOM...